# Frobenius endomorphism why $p$ has to be prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was doing a homework and to Prove that if $p$ is prime and if $R$ is a commutative ring of characteristic $p$, then $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ for all $a,b\in R$. 
Namely https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism
However, I proved it through binomial coefficient and there was no need for $p$ to be prime. But obviously everywhere $p$ was prime was a given condition.

Why $p$ was prime was listed as a condition here?

My proof:
$(a+b)^p=\sum_{k=0}^p\binom{p}{k}a^kb^{n-k}=a^p+b^p+\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{k}a^kb^{n-k}$, where each term in $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{k}a^kb^{n-k}$ involve a $p$ factor on the top of the binomial coefficient. Thus $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{k}a^kb^{n-k}=(1+1+...+1)$(p terms)$*$ something $=0$.
Thus  $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$. Done.

Comment: Do you have $n \ |\ {n \choose k}$ when $n$ is not prime ? (try with $n = 2p$)

Comment: But $\binom{p}{k}=\frac{p!}{(p-k)!k!}$. for $k=1,2,...p-1$ there always a $p$ at the top. where $p=1+1+...+1=0$, Why diviation?

Comment: $p$ is prime. Look at ${2p \choose p}$.

Comment: There is always a $p$ at the top, but if $p$ is not prime, then some factors at the bottom may cancel some or all of the $p$ at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $p$ prime because ${{p}\choose{k}} \equiv 0\ mod\ p$ for $k=1,2,..,p-1$ iff $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 0):

For example, 
$\displaystyle 
 \left\{\binom n4 \right\}_{n=0}^4 
 = \{1,4,6,4,1\}$ and $4 \nmid 6$.

Visually, look at $\displaystyle \binom 75$, for example.

$$\binom 75 = \binom 72 =
  \dfrac {1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7}
         {1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 1 \cdot 2} 
  = 3 \cdot 7$$

Notice that, since all of the numbers in the denominator are less than $7$ and because $7$ is a prime number, none of these numbers will have a common factor greater than $1$ with $7$. This will ensure that the seven does not get cancelled or reduced by any of the numbers in the denominator. The only exceptions to this will be at 
$\displaystyle \binom 70 = \binom 77 = 1$.

It should be clear then why $\displaystyle p \left | \binom pk \right.$ for all integers $1 < k < p$.